# Check if Android device is rooted or not

Tags: android

If in case we have got used android device can any one please tell that how we can check whether it is rooted or not ? As while developing android applications, some times there arises a need to root the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this Root checker app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.student.studio.app.rootchecker

Answer (score 0):

There is an app [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en) that will check if the device has root access or not. It just checks if apps has super user access or not.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on device model, in nexus device you can see lock image while booting, in other some devices you can see super user app in app list.

Answer (score 0):

[RootTools](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/tree/master/RootTools/src/com/stericson/RootTools) try this, you can do some check or other things